# The ${'foo %(a)s bar %(b)s' % {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}} syntax doesn't work in a Mako template

Tags: python, templates, mako

In a [Mako](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mako_%28template_engine%29) template, I need to do something like:

```
${'foo %(a)s bar %(b)s' % {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}}
```

When A do that, I get this error:

> SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) unexpected EOF while parsing  
>   (, line 1) ("'foo %(a)s bar %(b)s' % {'a': '1', 'b': '2'") in file…

How do I fix this issue?

I need to use this syntax in translated text:

```
$(_(u'foo bar %(a)s ... %(b)s) % { ... })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around is to pass the dict object in a different way. For example:

```
from mako.template import Template

print Template("${'foo %(a)s bar %(b)s' % data}").render(data=dict(a='Alpha',b='Beta'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
${'foo %(a)s bar %(b)s' % dict((('a', '1'), ('b', '2'),))}
```